# python3 replace a empty line with fileinput

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file that has empty line between each line like this:

```
line one

line two

line three
```

I want to append a line after line two

This is how I am trying to do it

```
for line_num, line in enumerate(fileinput.FileInput(file, inplace=1) ):
                if line_num == 4:
                    line.replace(" ", 'line to append')
```

The problem with this is it overwrites the entire file when I want to append the line

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has a few (small) issues.

1. you do not `print` the lines to the file
2. `line_num == 4` will not write after `line two`, unless you use `enumerate` with `start=1`
3. (assuming that you want to fill an empty line) `line.replace(' ', 'line to append')` will not do the trick because an empty line does contain a space

Try:

```py
>>> import fileinput
>>> with fileinput.input('test', inplace=True) as f:
...     for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
...          if line_num == 3 and line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
...              line = 'line to append\n'
...          print(line, end='')
...
```

`test` had originally the content in your description and after:

```
$ cat test
line one

line two
line to append
line three
```

`line_num == 3 and line in ['\n', '\r\n']` says "find the 4th line and check if it is empty". You may want to update/replace the checks based on your needs.